# Invalid column name EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've read all post and articles that i could find and none solve this extremely weird problem with EF.

I have a context that map a table call "Thing".

```
 [Table("Tbl_Thing")]
    public class Thing
    {
        [Column("dbThingNumber"),Key, DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Decimal ThingId { get; set; }

        [Column("dbBatch")]
        public int? BatchId { get; set; }

        [Column("dbPeople")]
        public int? People { get; set; }

        [Column("dbFileID")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Column("dbFilePath")]
        public int? PathId { get; set; }
}
```

When i query the table "Thing" on the home screen, setting, groups, etc, etc, works like a charm:

```
class ThingService{

private Context context;

public ThingService(Context context)
{
this.context = context;
}

public List<Thing> GetThingsByPeopleId(int id)
{
return context.Thing.Where(x=>x.People == id);
}


}
```

So in another class i have this.

```
var thingService = new ThingService(new Context());
var thingsByPeople = thingService.GetThingsByPeopleId(4);
```

Yeah, here is rocks and work SO well.

But when i make the same thing(same method, same id, same context and in the same process) in a class named "ThingsArticles" i get:

```
Invalid column name dbFilePath.
```

dbFilePath is not a FK, not AU... Is just a normal INTEGER column, here the script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Thing](
    [dbThingNumber] [decimal](10, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dbBatch] [int] NULL,
    [dbApplication] [int] NULL,
    [dbFileID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dbFilePath] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This error is kind of crazy since it there are in another places(clases) that works and others that don't without no explination of why and that is the only column that fail.

Where in the workign class i have:

```
var thingService = new ThingService(new Context());
var thingsByPeople = thingService.GetThingsByPeopleId(4);// exactly the same, i just copy and pasted it.
```

What could be happend? Its there anythig that im missing?

Update:

Entity framework version: 6

Update 2:

I also use the context directly and the same thing happen:

```
context.Thing.Where(x=>x.People == 2);// the same error is throw
```

How i call the ThingArticle:

```
class Article {
private Context context;
public Article(Context context)
{
this.context = context;
}

public List<Article> GetArticleInfo(int id)
{

var thingService = new ThingService(context);
var PeopleThings = thingService.GetThingsByPeopleId(id);// here error throw

// and more code...
}

}
```

Comment: can you show us ho you are call ThingsArticle along with thingsByPeople?  Does ThingsArticle fail all the time?  Is there any data that you can share just to see it?  Do you need a FirstOrDefault?

Comment: take a look now and tell me if that i what you need more.

Comment: where the id == 2 what does the table have for values?

Comment: the table contains 6235 rows, not data can be delete so its start from 1,2,3,4... to 6235 rows, and all rows have data(there is not null)

Comment: I think you accidentally put two entities in one project. Otherwise why it would say to you "Invalid column name dbFilePath." Probably you didn't refresh your entity in your other class. Plus check your connection string. Make sure you are using only one entity object.

Comment: Can you verify that your context is pointing to the correct DB?  I don't know if you have different environments.

Comment: @webdad3 yes, the connectionstring is pointhing the correct DB.